# Replace implementation of bean in spring library project

Tags: java, spring, aop, bpp

I would like to replace the implementation of all created beans of a certain class with proxy with changed logic and additional @Autowired beans there.

I have interface:

```
public interface Fooable {
    void foo();
}
```

implementation:

```
public class FooImpl implements Fooable {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void foo2() {
        //do smth
    }
}
```

proxy:

```
public class FooProxy implements Fooable {
    private final FooImpl fooImpl;
    private final SomethingAutowired somethingAutowired;

    //constructor

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        fooImpl.foo2();
        somethingAutowired.bar();
    }
}
```

client bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Fooable fooable1() {
        return new FooImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public Fooable fooable2() {
        return new FooImpl();
    }
}
```

I've try to solve this problem in several ways:

- AOP - problem solved, I just register aspect that I want, but I don't like this way.
- BPP - I replace bean implementation to proxy class in postProcessAfterInitialization, but I can't autowire custom beans there.
- BFPP - I changed setBeanClassName, but it doesn't help and as I read this problem shouldn't be solved by BFPP.

I have 2 more ideas, but they are very strange:

- in BPP save beans in postProcessBeforeInitialization that are needed in the proxy constructor and substitute them in after method
- in BFPP deregister old bean and register proxy, but idk how to approach this

But I'm sure that there are more clean and beautiful way to solve this.

Comment: Would registering the FooProxy as a Fooable bean and using @Primary to return it work?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X thank you, very interesting approach, I'm gonna try it and feedback a little bit later

Comment: @experimentunit1998X doesn't help when I have multiple Fooable beans in my client app :(

Comment: Can you clarify why it doesnt help? Is it because some of the Fooable beans needs to be that specific bean, and not the FooProxy? Thus, when the @Primary "replaces" the autowired bean, it causes unwanted behavior in some places?

Comment: Client creates 2 instances of original class, in result I should give him 2 instances of proxy class. But @Primary will set just one main implementation of interface.

Comment: I need change fooimpl1 to fooproxy1, fooimpl2 to fooproxy2. Don’t think that scope prototype helps me in this, maybe I don’t understand the idea

Comment: _"AOP - problem solved, I just register aspect that I want, but I don't like this way."_ With all due respect, if you do not like Spring's simple solution to your problem and want to find a more complicated one, why is that? Do you have too much spare time?